# Get and Alert All z:row Elements

Tags: jquery, spservices, xml

I am using SPServices to get the list items I want returned to me from a specific list.  I know how to find a particular element using this the GetListItems function without a problem.  Is there a way to loop through all of the z:row elements and store all of the returned ows_ values in an array?

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z"row").each(function(){
    //I know this is how to get it by calling it directly

      var xitem = $(this);
      var title = xitem.attr("ows_Title");

   //Is there a way to get them all at once?

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: listName,
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Values'/></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: Function.createDelegate(this, callback)
});

callback = function (xData, Status) {
    var values = new Array();
    jQuery(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {           
        values.push(jQuery(this).attr('Values'));
    });
};
```

**Update**

```
jQuery(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {   
    jQuery.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib) {
        values.push(attrib.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but ows_Values is not a literal return.  I will fix my question.  I need to get all pf the elements in each z:row all of the ows_whatevertheyare elements.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @lazoDev: See my updated answer. The code is not tested. So you might need to fix here and there, but the concept will work for sure.